# VBA - `For Each` syntax - row and table internal enumerators

Tags: vba

I don't understand Excels behavior on the following:
1. This works fine (`cell` is defined as range object, but is actually a cell used fr looping a range: `For Each cell In MyTable`):

```
For i = 1 To Len(CompetID)
    If InStr(1, cell.Offset(0, colOff), Mid(CompetID, i, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next i
```

However, this results in a Type Mismatch Error on the `InStr` row:

```
For Each RowCell In HelpTable.Rows(helpRow)
    If InStr(1, RowCell, Mid(BrandID, 1, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next RowCell
```

`RowCell` is a Range, just as `cell` is; doublechecked that in the Immediate window. `BrandID` is a string of length 1 - also checked. I used the `Mid` function just in case, to force a string. `HelpTable.Rows(helpRow)` also works fine - checked previously using selection.

`RowCell` could be blank, but according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811%28v=office.15%29.aspx), that should just return "0" on the function.

I also tried to use `Str(RowCell)` and `RowCell.Value`, but this resulted in an Excel crash.

I am obviously missing something, but I can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you give range of 'cell'?

Comment: @newjenn `cell` is looping through another range: `For Each cell In MyTable`. I edited the initial post  bit to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For Each RowCell In HelpTable.Rows(helpRow)` executes once per row, and `RowCell` contains entire row (within the table borders).

`.Value` or a multicell `Range` is a `Variant/Array`. This cannot be passed to `InStr`.

Use `For Each RowCell In HelpTable.Rows(helpRow).Cells` to iterate through row's cells.

Comment: I see your point here, but then why is the first piece of code working?

Comment: Because there `cell` is a single cell each time. Put `MsgBox RowCell.Address` in your loop.

Comment: use Cstr() method to convert RowCell.value  to string. ie Cstr(RowCell.value)

Comment: @GSerg : I see. So a row is not a range, but a collection of cells. That's the part I was missing. While the `For Each cell In MyTable` already uses `MyTable` as a range. Is this right ?

Comment: @horace_vr Both a row and a table are ranges (collections of cells). There is no difference between a row and a table with one row. It's just that internally the `For Each` syntax relies on hidden enumerators, and when you call `In HelpTable.Rows(helpRow)` you hit the table's enumerator that enumerates rows. You want then enumerate `Cells` of the row this enumerator returned. When you call `In MyTable`, you implicitly hit the `MyTable.Cells` enumerator.